# Ado.net entity data model doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, ado.net

I've intalled vs2008 ts on my windows 7 x64 pc, but when I tried to add ado.net entity  data model there is no template for it. All the MSDN tutorials say that vs2008 has it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [VS2008 Service Pack 1.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)